# How to resolve a promise from another function

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, resolve

I don't get how to resolve a promise from an other function.

How can **1.** tell to blabla() 'mail received' by sending the mail?

1. This email module manage the mails, it fire 'new' when we receive an email.

`mail.on('new', function(mail) {})`

2. This module do stuff and **at some point must wait for the_mail**, before continuing.

   ```
   function blabla() {
       [.. I do stuff ..]
       console.log('now we must wait for a new mail')
       const the_mail = await waiting_for_mail()
       [.. I can continue stuff (I have the mail) ..]
   }
   ```

   - The two modules must be separated, they perform != tasks.
   - The first manage the mails, the second manage SMS.
   - waiting_for_mail() isn't defined, I guess that I have to use this logic.

Comment: Where and how is `waiting_for_mail` defined? Is it an async function or does it return a Promise?

Comment: I didn't define it yet, I guess it's the logic that I should use as I must "wait" for the mail.

Comment: Please provide your actual code so we can help identify the issue much easier.

Comment: In that case, `waiting_for_mail` should return a Promise which resolves to the received mail.

Comment: Ok, how do you do that? That's my question. When I receive an email, how can I let know blabla() so blabla() can continue his job, with the mail received

Comment: How to resolve the promise from mail.on('new') function(mail) ? As the promise is defined in an other function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have very little to go on here, but here's a suggestion from what I could gather:

```
function waiting_for_mail() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        mail.once('new', resolve);
    });
}
```

Comment: It probably should use `mail.once()`, to unsubscribe the listener when it's called